# How to I achieve an all-white image that blends into the background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, monochrome

The foreground image is a black and white and set to "Multiply". I want all the dark hues to be replaced with whites.

[image]

Comment: Hawoabout Invert image?

Comment: You mean like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5e3U.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's nor clear what is wanted, so I place some guesses.If you want darker shades more in BW and less in red, you can put your image to the layer mask of the red layer. On the top there's the multiplying original BW image.

Here the leftmost image is the assumed original image and the red one is the result. If you want a steep treshold, you can treshold the layer mask.

[image]

You can directly edit the layer mask by clicking at first its icon. To be able to paste something into the mask, click the icon holding Alt at the same time. Use paste in place, if you want to  get exact placement.

If you literally want to change everything darker than a known limit to white, you have several possiblities. One way is to add a white layer which is masked by the inverted original image. The steepness of the whitening can be adjusted by adjusting the levels of the mask.

[image]

Here the curves tool is applied to the layer mask of the white.

The guessing goes on. Here the blacks are turned to white, all dark is now light red. The inverted original BW image is colorized to red:

[image]

This is not a guess or at least it's not my guess. It's suggested by user @joojaa in a comment:

[image]

The BW image is used as a layer mask for red. Black reveals underlying white fully, greys make red partially transparent.

Comment: Hide the roiginal multiply in last image

Comment: @joojaa Why - it will change nearly black to light red, I tried to change dark  shades to light grey.

Comment: You are tainting the white with black color getting you that interesting gayish tint

Comment: @joojaa I'll do it later (=as soon as I get my own guess list ready)

Answer (score 2):

1. Highlight the image layer
2. Choose `Image > Adjustments > Invert` from the menu
3. Change the layer Blending mode to `Screen`